My Comfyui running through Homebrew on my Intel Mac will not recognise the new PIP 24.3.1 even though its installed?
I was trying to update the custom nodes in Comfyui, however, I keep getting the attached error that: [notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.0 -> 24.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
However:
(base) mattimac5k@Matts-iMac comfyui % python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Users/mattimac5k/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages (24.3.1)
I am a designer  not a programmer, so I have little technical knowledge other than copying and pasting code into the MAC TERMIANL
I would really appreciate any help as I've exhausted all available options I've found on the net.

I have tried the following with no luck:

updated Homebrew
reinstalled Confyui


Are you certain that ComfyUI is running the same python as you run when invoking python3.  If it's anything like my experience with Stable Diffusion on Linux, then I have to build my own Python 3.10 in order to make it work.
